# How to handle the SKIP button in authorization dialog?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, skip

I'm asking for the `publish_stream` permission and if a user clicks the [SKIP button in this dialog](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/851557_535801936465660_169463870_n.png), the app won't work.
Is there a way to make the permission explicit, so the SKIP button is not displayed?